How to store files in offchain worker and its hash in blockchain?
Can offchain worker be used for storing large files. I want to eliminate third party ipfs gateways for storing files.
I need a code example for uploading and storing files in offchain worker and its hash in blockchain state. But unable to find any example code
I am thinking to use rust-libp2p file sharing example, and integrate with server based frontend App or desktop app, not sure which way to go and is better. Also need to monetize and tip the server or peer id for maintenance. Its difficult to use csr frontend as one can't know which peer to use for upload.
